# How can increase the performance of the query below without using distinct keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 table to record data. For example, İf you logged in, your informations are recorded into table1. When you logged in second time, your informations are recorded into table 1 and  your previous enterance information shifts into table2. Tables have too much rows. To conclude, I want to get the number of different users have logged in with the given ip address for the last 60 days. Ip is the input for sql statement. However, I have performance issue in my sql query. *(Two table have same structure and please ignore indexing for your suggestions)* Also, is the any way to get  totCount using without distinct and another select keyword.
Thanks

Here is my sql:

```
 select distinct count(*) over() as totCount 
 into p_differentCustomerCount
 from (
      select t1.customerNo,t1.customerIp,t1.lastlogindate from table1 t1
      union all 
      select t2.customerNo,t2.customerIp,t2.lastlogindate from table2 t2
      )t
 where t.lastlogindate > sysdate - 60 
       and t.customerIp= "IP_As_Input"
 group by customerNo;
```

Comment: Remove the `union all`.  It is doing nothing.  Your description mentions two tables, but your query only references one.

Comment: Do you want *the number of different users have logged in with the same ip* for each ip? Or is it just the total number? Clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the `count` of distinct users who logged in with same ip. So my suggestion would be to use direct `where` clause. Not on inner view.

Something like this:

```
select count(1) as totCount 
 into p_differentCustomerCount
 from (
      select customerNo 
        from table1
       Where lastlogindate > sysdate - 60 
         And customerIp= 'IP_As_Input'
      union -- gives distinct result
      select customerNo 
        from table2
       Where lastlogindate > sysdate - 60 
         And customerIp= 'IP_As_Input'
      )
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the number of different users have logged in with the same ip for the last 60 days.

You seem to want:

```
select count(*)
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.customerNo = t1.customerNo and
                        t2.customerIp <> t1.customerIp and
                        t2.lastlogindate >= sysdate - 60
                 );
```

I am not sure why you have a filter on the ip.  It is not mentioned in the text.

Comment: Ip is passed as input to sql query. So I have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the number of different users have logged in with the same ip for the last 60 days.

It appears you want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERNO)`, not `DISTINCT COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT z.CUSTOMERNO) AS CUSTOMER_COUNT
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM TABLE2) z
  WHERE z.CUSTOMERIP = 'wh.at.ev.ah' AND
        z.LASTLOGINDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '60' DAY
```

But you say you don't want to use the `DISTINCT` keyword. Very well:

```
SELECT SUM(RN) AS CUSTOMER_COUNT
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY z.CUSTOMER_NO) AS RN
          FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM TABLE2) z
          WHERE z.CUSTOMERIP = 'wh.at.ev.ah' AND
                z.LASTLOGINDATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '60' DAY
          HAVING RN = 1)
```

Comment: Jarvis - Reinstate, yes that's  true but I have to solve it by 3 select statement